# How to align the layouts properly in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I want to align a scrollable `TextView` above a `RelativeLayout`) with 3 buttons at the bottom  and a `SeekBar` above this buttons. The problem with my code is that the `RelativeLayout` takes the entire screen.

Here's my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.acer.aartisangrah.ekdanta">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b9"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:onClick="decrease"
    android:background="@drawable/zoomout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/b10"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="increase"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/zoomin1"/>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/play"/>

    <SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b9"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/b10"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/b10"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/b10"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eg5Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Change the height of the ScrollView to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
 and remove the `android:layout_weight="1"`

Answer (score 0):

The following layout should do the job. Firstly, there was a circular dependency in height among `<RelativeLayout>` and `<SeekBar>`, so I fixed the height of `<SeekBar>`. Secondly, the `android:layout_alightParentBottom="true"` was messing with the layout manager, so removed that. Finally, moved the `<SeekBar>` above the buttons to easily manage the layout description. Here's the updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/images"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.example.acer.aartisangrah.ekdanta">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/b10"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="decrease"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
            android:background="@drawable/zoomout1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="increase"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/zoomin1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/play"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The seekbar pointer is aligned properly with the line....the pointer is slightly upward to the line

Comment: @Devk If you're talking about `<SeekBar>` then you need to remove `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` from it. This should  do it in my layout above: <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/b10"/>

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: The seekkar must start with the lower left button. Its coming up fine to me. I cannot understand whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you set `ScrollView`  `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:gravity="center">
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

so `ScrollView` takes nothing for hight

### Edit

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

You can set `android:layout_weight="1"` as you want ratio between ScollView and RelativeLayout. Hare both will get half(1/2) of screen.

Comment: i dont want it 1/2 the screen....the buttons and the seekbar contained in the relative layout should be at the bottom.....i want it like the whatsapp

Comment: no i mean scrollView will take half and relative layout will take rest half of screen...

Comment: i try your code...it's 100% ok as you want. just try i as say afer Edit..